# Entity Framework Core exception renaming column

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-core

I have a .Net6 WinForms application using Entity Framework Core 6.0.3 and I am trying to read a simple table from a SQL Server database. I need to rename the column so that it is different in the model than what it is called in the database.

Normally (in EF6, I would add a [Column()] attribute on the property with the new name. However, when I do that it throws an exception reading the data 'Invalid column name' for whatever the new name is.

I have also tried using the modelBuilder and calling the HasColumnName() but get the same error.  If I remove the attribute/model builder reference, then no exception occurs, except that I am stuck with the old column name.

```
[Table("RefTable1")
public partial class SpecialReferenceTable
{
   public Int32 Id { get; set;}
   [MaxLength(300)]
   [Column("NewRefColumn"]   // Throws exception Column does not exist: NewRefColumn
   public String? OldRefColumn {get;set;}
}
```

Is there something I am missing with renaming column in Core?

Comment: isnt it the other way round, the column attribute is the name in the DB, the c# name is the name you want to use for it

Comment: the old col name already exists in the DB - you can't just add an attribute to make it magically change without doing a migration (eg code first)

Comment: I appreciate the replies. In EF6 adding the column attribute was a way to refer to columns by alternate names.  This feature does not seem to exist in EF Core (and using fluid does not seem to work either).  It is quite common when accessing a single database with multiple applicates to refer to the fields in context of the application not of the database. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Column("Column name")]  is used for the name of the column in the database table and the name of the property you have is the one you want to change.

Comment: Thanks - in other words, my original example had the fields the wrong way round.